# Does E-Verify provide API to verify the eligibility of employee?

Tags: e-verify

E-Verify is a web-based system that allows enrolled employers to confirm the eligibility of their employees to work in the United States.

We are planning to integrate E-Verify in our HR system, to do verification work automatically.

It seems E-Verify only supports create a verification case on the browser, Is there API provide by E-Verify for developers?

How did you implement this feature?

### Reference

https://www.e-verify.gov

https://www.uscis.gov/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can following this instruction to apply for API access permission.

1. There are three types of E-Verify account, Please register E-Verify as an agent account.
2. Then, attend the online train and pass the exam.
3. once you passed the exam, you can apply for a sandbox account.
4. waiting for days.
5. login [staging environment](https://stage.e-verify.uscis.gov/) to access the Swagger Document.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, it's called E-Verify web services